Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit (read_sav)
I am working with R in VS code and I am facing this error whenever I want to view tbl_df from read_sav function.
Error: C stack usage  7956480 is too close to the limit
Interestingly, I don't get this error on R Studio.
Here is a reproducible example:
library(haven)
path <- system.file("examples", "iris.sav", package = "haven")
df <- read_sav(path)
view(df)

Changing to data.frame doesn't solve the issue.
Update:
sessionInfo() 

R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS 15.1.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] haven_2.5.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4      R6_2.5.1        tzdb_0.4.0      magrittr_2.0.3 
 [5] glue_1.8.0      tibble_3.2.1    pkgconfig_2.0.3 lifecycle_1.0.4
 [9] readr_2.1.5     cli_3.6.3       fansi_1.0.6     vctrs_0.6.5    
[13] compiler_4.4.1  forcats_1.0.0   hms_1.1.3       pillar_1.9.0   
[17] rlang_1.1.4     jsonlite_1.8.9

Thanks.

That means you ran out of memory. If this is unexpected, then you probably have fallen into a recursion.

Have you tried uppercase View(df)? I'm not sure where the lowercase view comes from but it doesn't come from haven. But where ever it comes from it sounds like it's recursively calling itself.

Yes, and it gives the same error. The lower case view comes from tibble which I think it calls View.

Can you add the output of sessionInfo() to your original post?

I've updated the post and added the output.

I had the same problem. No Idea what causes it. But what helped me was saving the df as csv and then loading it in again. No more problems!
